# Is viewing an integer as an array of smaller integers UB?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

Is viewing an integer as an array of smaller integers UB?

For example, is there UB in this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm> // sort

void sort_bytes(std::uint32_t& x) {
    std::uint8_t* p = (std::uint8_t*)&x;

    std::sort(p, p+4);
}

void sort_words(std::uint32_t& x) {
    std::uint16_t* p = (std::uint16_t*)&x;

    std::sort(p, p+2);
}


int main() {
    const std::uint32_t x = 1234342542u;
    std::uint32_t y = x, z = x;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    sort_bytes(y);
    std::cout << y << std::endl;
    sort_words(z);
    std::cout << z << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: It breaks [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).

Comment: `char` and `unsigned char` can alias anything, so the first snippet is fine (assuming `uint8_t` == `unsigned char`). The second one is UB.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what the *strict aliasing rule* forbids. However, compilers generally have options to disable reliance on this rule, e.g. `-fno-strict-aliasing` for GCC and Clang, with which the behavior will be defined in the practical sense on these compilers. Otherwise the these compilers *will* compile it in unintended ways because the aliasing rule is broken, causing UB.

`sort_bytes` is probably an exception. `uint8_t` is typically `unsigned char`. `unsigned char` specifically has an exception to the aliasing rule and may alias any other type (but not the other way around).

Therefore `sort_bytes` is fine from that perspective. However, what value exactly will be read is implementation-defined and dependent on the representations of the involved types. In practice it is especially relevant whether the system is litte-endian or big-endian (or something else entirely).

However, even with the aliasing exception, the standard technically at the moment doesn't permit treating the result of the cast as pointing into an array. That's however probably a defect that will be resolved eventually.

Comment: *"even with the aliasing exception, the standard technically at the moment doesn't permit treating the result of the cast as pointing into an array"*. So even `sort_bytes` is UB currently?

Comment: @MWB Technically yes (in the sense of the ISO standard). But it will work on every compiler I am aware of (assuming `uint8_t` is `unsigned char`). Just because something is undefined in the standard doesn't mean that compilers won't have a defined behavior for it, especially if it is generally agreed that the standard is just insufficient or defect. However, the effect of the sorting will depend on endianess and representation more generally, as I wrote.

Comment: @MWB the standard talks about "undefined behavior" and "implmentation defined behavior". While the latter requires an implementation to define and document the behavior, an implementation can of course also define and document things that the standard leaves undefined.